# Iterative vertex removal algorithm

Tags: graphs

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph, where $|V|=n$,$|E|=m$,$k=m/n$.

We consider the following algorithm:

> while (there exists $u ∈ V (G)$ such that $d_G(u) < k$) do
>
> $\quad G ← G − u$;

Prove that the resulting $G$ isn't null.

Implementing the algorithm is easy, but I can't find a way to prove it rigorously.
k doesn't change over time.

Comment: What is $dG(u)$?

Comment: Does $k$ get updated to reflect new values of $\frac{|E|}{|V|}$ after each iterations? Or it is just initialized once at start.

Comment: We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercise-style problems for you is unlikely to achieve that.  We're not looking for posts that consist of just the statement of an exercise style-task. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Answer (score 1):

After removing the first vertex, the new graph has $n' := n-1$ vertices and $m' := m-d_G(u) > m-k$ edges. Therefore
$$
\frac{m'}{n'} > \frac{m-k}{n-1} = k.
$$
Continuing in this way, we see that at any point in time, the ratio between edges and vertices is always at least $k$. Any graph on $\ell$ vertices has a ratio of at most $\binom{\ell}{2}/\ell = \frac{\ell-1}{2}$, so the number of vertices always satisfies $\ell \geq 2k+1$. In other words, when the algorithm terminates, there will be at least $2k+1$ vertices left.